# Controls on the Status bar got disappeared?

Tags: c#, winforms

Explanation : I have placed few labels on status bar. But somehow it got disappeared. Code uses those controls are still valid, I can't see any where in the window. I am using C#.net.

Comment: Post your code and debug through first to find if the controls are being rendered or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check the position of the controls and check with form's relative position.
Or if you select the control name from the properties menu, the control will be selected in form and then you can try brining it to front.

Comment: I selected the label, but even it is not seen. :(

Comment: It must have gotten positioned else where. check the top and left for the controls